# Android parse.com + facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am working on parse.com where I am trying to integrate facebook. But I am getting

> 09-23 12:41:32.706: E/AndroidRuntime(23440):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.FacebookSdk

On the given line

```
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Placed `ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.1.jar and Parse-1.10.1.jar` in libs folder.

This is the question asked many times in SOV...but I don't get any suitable answer...Any one have any idea what can be done to resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: can you comment how is project `order and export` hierarchy is it in `build path`.  your `src` should be last in `order hierarchy`

Comment: Android 4.2.2,Android Libraries,Dependencies, src and last is gen...but I don't think hierarchy sequence matters

Comment: Is `ParseFacebookUtilsV4.jar` comes under `private Lib`  or `Referenced`. some time it should come under `Private`

Comment: As I mentioned ParseFacebookUtilsV4.jar placed in libs folder ...its a private Lib..